# How to pass dynamic variable inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array which has name with current id inside my function:

```
$scope.expand = function(hodid, supid, leader_id, staff_id, importance){
  var tr_id = 'expand_tree_'+hodid;
```

In console output it will look like this: `expand_tree_1000321`
That's how my array will look in the end:

```
  $scope[tr_id] = {firstLevel:[$scope.firstLevelLst], secondLevel:[$scope.secondLevelLst], thirdLevel:[data_third]};
};
```

Now I want to print this `$scope[tr_id]` inside `ng-repeat` where `tAttrs.treeid` is id of the selected user:

```
<div  ng-repeat="first in ['expand_tree_'+tAttrs.treeid].firstLevel['0']">
  {{first.username}}
</div>
```

But it doesnt print anything. How can I print scope array inside `ng-repeat` with dynamic variable?

Comment: I edited my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it looks like you are using `$scope` as your data object.  This is not good for a couple reasons.  Use an object on the scope instead like:

```
$scope.data = {};
```

And store the data like:

```
$scope.data[tr_id] = {
    firstLevel: [$scope.firstLevelLst],
    secondLevel: [$scope.secondLevelLst],
    thirdLevel: [data_third]
};
```

But don't wrap the properties in an array, since they are already arrays:

```
$scope.data[tr_id] = {
    firstLevel: $scope.firstLevelLst,
    secondLevel: $scope.secondLevelLst,
    thirdLevel: data_third
};
```

Then you can loop through `first` like:

```
<div ng-repeat="first in data['expand_tree_' + tAttrs.treeid].firstLevel">
    {{first.username}}<br />
</div>
```

Here is a [**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/0jxq4mnb/)